# Python Variable Separation between Objects

Tags: python, object, scope, variable-assignment

I do not understand the output of my code shown below. I expect to see:

```
1
1
```

but instead see:

```
1
2
```

This is the code in question using Python 2.7.3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Test:
    __tBin = {'80':0, '70':0, '60':0, '50':0,'40':0,
              '30':0, '20':0, '10':0, '0':0,
              '-10':0, '-20':0, '-30':0, '-40':0}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__tests = {'i2c_transfer':self.__tBin}

    def foo(self):
        self.__tests['i2c_transfer']['80'] += 1
        print self.__tests['i2c_transfer']['80']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testList = list()
    for i in range(1, 3):
        testList.append(Test())

    for i in testList:
        i.foo()
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect that? `__tBin` is a *class* attribute, the first call to `foo` modifies it and that's why you see `2` the second time. In your `__init__` it looks like you want to make a *copy* of it, but you have to do it explicitly: `'ic2_transfer': self.__tBin.copy()`

Comment: Ah, thanks. Like I said below, this was my first time using Python and I guess I didn't look at the documentation close enough which is why I would expect what I thought. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the dictionary `__tBin`, you're actually creating it as a *Class* object, rather than as an *instance* object. So when you do `self.__tests['i2c_transfer']['80'] += 1`, that new value persists throughout each instance of the class. So if you were to change it to:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__tBin = {'80':0, '70':0, '60':0, '50':0,'40':0,
                  '30':0, '20':0, '10':0, '0':0,
                  '-10':0, '-20':0, '-30':0, '-40':0}
        self.__tests = {'i2c_transfer':self.__tBin}
```

You should get what you're looking for. self.__tBin instantiates the dictionary as an instance object, and so it'll be reset each time you instantiate the class.

Comment: Ah thank you, this is my first time using Python and never realized that about dict's.

Comment: Happy to help. Keep in mind that it's not about the _dict_, per se, but about the class. When you create attributes without self preceding, the attribute becomes a class attribute. So any time you modify a class attribute, that modification persists through all instances of the class, regardless of what the attribute is.